# Can't undo in XAML designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I'm working with the XAML editor in Visual Studio 2013 for a WPF project, and I found that I can't undo when I make changes in the visual designer, which is quite frustrating when I make a mistake. I can undo when I make changes in the XAML source editor, just not in the designer. I could have sworn I could do this in previous versions of Visual Studio - was the functionality removed for some reason?

Comment: Actually, sometimes I can't even undo in the XAML source editor either...

Comment: Try restarting Visual Studio... that's not at all normal... unless you're running your project... then not being able to edit is normal.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, and it didn't help, but then another time I opened up my project again, and it mysteriously started working...

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft connect told me to do this and it solved my problem

`devenv /resetuserdata general`

Comment: where do we do this ?

Comment: Depending on the OS you're using, for instance Windows 10 you just right click the START button and you click on RUN and enter devenv /resetuserdata general